# How to sort JSON data in ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, sorting, angularjs-filter

I am getting a server response and binding these data to view using ng-repeat. Now I want to sort these data by `priceList` and `name`. I am able to sort name using `orderBy`, but not with `priceList`. I want to sort the products based on `priceList`. Sorting with name will change the order of list while sorting by `priceList` will effect only the order of `products` of each `category`. It will effect the order of displayed category. Please help me resolve this.
My code:

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <pre>Sorting predicate = {{predicate}};</pre>
    <hr/>
    <table class="friend">
        <tr>
            <th><a href="" ng-click="predicate = 'name'; reverse=false">Name</a>
            </th>
            <th><a href="" ng-click="predicate = 'priceList'>price</a></th>
        </tr>

    </table>


<div ng-repeat="data in _JSON[0].categories | orderBy:predicate">
       <div ng-repeat="vals in data.itemTypeResults |orderBy:'partTerminologyName'" id="{{vals.partTerminologyName}}">
`<h4 style="background-color: gray">{{vals.partTerminologyName}} : Position :{{vals.position}}</h4>`<br>


<div ng-repeat="val in vals.products">
    <b> Quantity:{{val[0].perCarQty}}</b><br>
    <b> part:{{val[0].partNo}}</b><br>
    <b>sku:{{val[0].sku}}</b><br>
    <b> qtyInStock:{{val[0].qtyInStock}}</b><br>
    <b> priceList:{{val[0].priceList}}</b><br>
    <b>priceSave:{{val[0].priceSave}}</b><br>
    <b> qtyDC:{{val[0].qtyDC}}</b><br>
    <b> qtyNetwork:{{val[0].qtyNetwork}}</b><br>
    <b> priceCore:{{val[0].priceCore}}</b><br>
        </div>
</div>      
    </div>
```

JS:

```
$scope._JSON = [
        {"categories":
            [
                {"id":14061,"name":"Drive Belts",
                    "itemTypeResults":[
                        {"partTerminologyName":"Serp. Belt",
                            "position":"Main Drive",
                            "products":{
                                "5060635":[
                                    {"perCarQty":2,"partNo":"5060635",
                                    "sku":"20060904","qtyInStock":2,"qtyNetwork":4,
                                    "qtyDC":6,"priceList":19.15,"priceSave":3.29,
                                    "priceCore":10.0}
                                ],
                                "635K6":[
                                    {"perCarQty":9,"partNo":"635K6",
                                        "sku":"10062449","qtyInStock":2,"qtyNetwork":4,
                                        "qtyDC":6,"priceList":18.15,"priceSave":3.21,"priceCore":10.0}
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {"id":2610,"name":"Drive Belt Tensioners, Idlers, Pulleys & Components",
                    "itemTypeResults":[
                        {"partTerminologyName":"Drive Belt Tensioner Assembly",
                        "position":"N/A",
                            "products":{
                                "950489A":[
                                    {"perCarQty":4,"partNo":"950489A",
                                        "sku":"10150833","qtyInStock":2,"qtyNetwork":4,
                                        "qtyDC":6,"priceList":18.15,"priceSave":3.21,"priceCore":10.0
                                    }
                                ]
                            }},
                        {"partTerminologyName":"Drive Belt Idler Pulley","position":"N/A",
                            "products":{
                                "89161":[
                                    {"perCarQty":1,"partNo":"89161",
                                    "sku":"99995959","qtyInStock":2,"qtyNetwork":4,
                                    "qtyDC":6,"priceList":17.15,"priceSave":3.21,"priceCore":10.0}
                                ],
                                "951373A":[
                                    {"perCarQty":2,"partNo":"951373A","pla":"LTN",
                                    "plaName":"Litens",
                                    "sku":"10150926","qtyInStock":2,"qtyNetwork":4,
                                        "qtyDC":6,"priceList":18.15,"priceSave":3.21,"priceCore":10.0}
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ];
    $scope.predicate = '';
```

Fiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c3VVL/49/)

Comment: `$filter('orderBy')(vals.products, "priceList" )`

ought to work

Comment: Can you update my fiddle. It will be helpful a lot for me.

Comment: `priceList` is not an attribute of any category. According to your JSON, Every category has multiple products, and each product is an array of elements each of which has a priceList. How exactly do you want to order the categories by priceList?

Comment: @abl price list is inside each products. If you see my fiddle than u will get idea. I am binding partTerminologyName as header data and inside it all products. No i want to sort using price.

Comment: @Ved I've seen the fiddle, and I repeat what I said. In your code, you are trying to order the categories by priceList: `ng-repeat="data in _JSON[0].categories | orderBy:predicate"` and `ng-click="predicate = 'priceList'`. Every category has multiple products. The price belongs to the product, not the category. How do you want to order the categories by price, when categories have no price? Perhaps you want to order the _products_ by price, inside each category?

Comment: Does anyone have a problem with the fiddle in this question?  I don't see the binding working for me in the output.

Comment: @abl i want to order product by price..

Comment: In order to make this work you have to implement a custom filter, cause the structure is really so complicated, or redesign your structure to fit your needs.

Comment: I have already created a fiddle for this, but not able to achieve the result.

Comment: @Ved are you stuck to this particular JSON format? The first thing I would do is see if I could return the format in a way the front end can work with more easily. If that is not an option, I would reorganize the data in a (Angular) service so that it is easier to display it using Angular.

Comment: I provided a simple example to reorganizing the JSON. Maybe you need to modify the API of the backend like the others says. If you have thousands of items and you need to modify the JSON to reorder the items you will have performance problems.

Comment: change partterminologyname to pricelist under ng-repeat it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to define a very good sorter function, or sort your `products` before they are interpreted by `ng-repeat`. I've created sorter function using underscore.js (or lodash).

You can checkout the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ruqrog8y/1/) (or the updated [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ruqrog8y/3/)). Products are first sorted by category and then sorted by price in every category.

```html
<!-- in html -->
<button ng-click="sortFn=sortByPrice">Sort By Price</button>
<button ng-click="sortFn=doNotSort">Do not Sort</button>
...
<div ng-repeat="val in sortFn(vals.products)">
  ...
```

```js
// in js
$scope.sortByPrice = function(products) {
  return _.sortBy(products, function(product) {
    return product.length > 0 ? product[0].priceList : 0;
  });
};

$scope.doNotSort = function(products) {
  return products;
};

$scope.sortFn = $scope.doNotSort; // do not sort by default
```

BTW: You are directly calling `val[0]`, which is very dangerous, if the product does not contain any elements, your code will break. My code won't ;-)

---

**Update 1**

The author asks me for a more pure Angular way solution.

Here is my answer: I think my solution is exactly in Angular way. Usually you can implement a filter (similar to `orderBy`) which wraps my `sortByPrice`. Why I don't do that, because you have `ng-click` to switch your order filter. I'd rather put control logic into a controller, not as pieces into view. This will be harder to maintain, when your project keeps growing.

---

**Update 2**

Okay, to make the `+50` worthy, here is the filter version you want, (typed with my brain compiler) Please check in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ruqrog8y/4/)

Comment: It seems good. But applying this will effect the view even 1 don't want to sort.

Comment: I got your point. So you can define a filter like `orderBy` with arguments, the first argument is the field to be sorted, the second argument is the products. I'd prefer use a `sortFn` which can direct to `sortByPrice` or `sortBySomething`. Please check my updated code above.

Comment: One thing i was wondering, can you do it in Angular way. I mean without using underScoreJS method.

Comment: I think you can simply take the implementation of `sortBy` from underscore. But I'd recommend use underscore (or lodash) as many as possible. This is a very convenience and performant library to handle arrays and objects.

Comment: I do understand this. But just wondering what would be Angular way implementation of this.

Comment: Exactly. I am trying this using filter that should work like orderBy. This update is almost previous approach.

Comment: What-if we use orderBy filter here?

Comment: @Ved please check update 2. I think this is what you exactly want. And I don't know, if `orderBy` supports to sort a property of one of its children object.

Comment: Will this work as previous one. I will apply on my code than check it. And thanks a lot for this.

Comment: But where is mySortByCategory method. I think you missed it to update.

Comment: @Ved pls check update 2 again, I've removed the third argument. Actually `mySortByCategory` can be replaced with any custom sort function. In your case it is a built-in `orderBy` with couple of arguments.

Comment: you helped me lot. So finally can you update fiddle. I got it but not working in my case.

Comment: @Ved please check the online demo, works exactly as you want http://jsfiddle.net/ruqrog8y/4/

Comment: again stucked .. My json changed and now it is not working.

Comment: @Ved maybe you should create a new question with your current json, so that we can help you solve your problem. Repeatedly update original question, might confuse other SO readers.

Comment: Solved. Thanks for response.

Answer (score 0):

You need to organize the products in other estructure. For example:

```
 $.each($scope._JSON[0].categories , function( i , e) {

        $.each(e.itemTypeResults, function(sub_i,sub_e) { 
        $.each(sub_e.products, function(itemTypeResults_i,product) {
            console.log(product);
            var aProduct = new Object();
          aProduct.priceList = product[0].priceList;
          aProduct.name = e.name;
            $scope.products.push(aProduct);  
        });

      } )

    });
```

The code is not very friendly but what i do is putt all the products in one array so they can be ordered by the price. You have the products inside categories so that's why angular is ordering by the price in each category.

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/7rL8fof6/1/

Hope it helps.

Comment: PD: I changed the prices and the names to test the code.

Comment: The thing is I want to sort products of each category,not the category. To sort category, I am able to do it using name.

Answer (score 0):

Your fiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/k5fkocby/2/

Basically:
1. Digested the complex json object into a flat list of objects:

```
var productsToShow = [];
for (var i=0; i < json[0].categories.length; i++){
    var category = json[0].categories[i];
    for (var j=0; j<category.itemTypeResults.length;j++){
    var item = category.itemTypeResults[j];       
    var products = item.products;    
    for (var productIndex in products) {
        var productItems = products[productIndex];
      for (var k=0; k<productItems.length;k++){
            var productItem = productItems[k];       

          // Additions:
          productItem.categoryName = category.name;                 
          productItem.partTerminologyName = item.partTerminologyName;
          productItem.position = item.position;                 

          productsToShow.push(productItem);          
        }
    }    
    } 
}
```

2. Show category title only when needed by:

   ng-repeat="product in (sortedProducts = (productsToShow | orderBy:predicate))"

and

```
ng-show="sortedProducts[$index - 1].partTerminologyName != product.partTerminologyName"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can sort from your database and get final JSON data..

```
db.categories.aggregate([{$group : {category : {your condition} },         price: {$sort : { price: 1 } },}}])
```